# Can I get dpkg to ignore an error returned from a post-installation script?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dpkg, apt

I am manually installing a .deb file (which I don't maintain) onto my Ubuntu system.

The package has a post-installation script which erroneously fails, and therefore the package is considered broken.

```
dpkg: error processing astah-community (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

This package is actually installed correctly and is working fine (the post-installation script is incorrect).  When I perform any apt operation on my system it now complains that the package is broken; how can I resolve this?

This doesn't help:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/the.deb --force-all
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can edit the post install script at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/astah-community.postinst` to comment out a portion that is failing. Or you can just rename/remove that file to prevent dpkg from running it at all.

Once you've done one of those you can use `dpkg --configure astah-community` to have dpkg retry the configuration process, and hopefully have that succeed.

Comment: Yes, that worked!  Thankyou.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too, just don't try to do it with aptitude, for some reason it keeps replacing my edited postinst script. But apt-get worked for me.

Comment: More details given here:

http://billauer.co.il/blog/2019/07/apt-install-force-installed/

Comment: Worked to remove  mysql-server failing on ubuntu 20. thanks. `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-*`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @qqx , I was able to fix issues with the `displaylink-driver`

After installing the latest displaylink drivers from their website, on ubuntu 23.04, I got error, but further up it also said the driver installed and reboot was needed. After rebooting, the displays connected to my USB-C docking station worked fine. But when I went to install other packages with `apt` I again got a portion of that error:

```
# apt install ./sublime-text_build-3211_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'sublime-text' instead of './sublime-text_build-3211_amd64.deb'
sublime-text is already the newest version (3211).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up displaylink-driver (5.7.0-129) ...


Reboot required
DisplayLink driver installed successfully.
Please reboot your computer to ensure the proper functioning of the software.


logname: no login name
logname: no login name
dpkg: error processing package displaylink-driver (--configure):
 installed displaylink-driver package post-installation script subprocess return
ed error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 displaylink-driver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so I edited `/var/lib/dpkg/info/displaylink-driver.postinst`
and changed this line:
`xorg_or_tty_running && exit 0`
to this:
`exit 0`

and `apt install` logs are clean now.