# Force remove package with dpkg despite errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I think this is Ubuntu Vivid specific as none of the existing solutions helps:

- [Can I get dpkg to ignore an error returned from a post-installation script?](https://superuser.com/questions/565809/can-i-get-dpkg-to-ignore-an-error-returned-from-a-post-installation-script)
- [Unable to remove package on Debian 7](https://superuser.com/questions/840178/unable-to-remove-package-on-debian-7)

All solutions I found so far suggest `dpkg --purge --force-all`, but this is what I get under Ubuntu Vivid:

```
% dpkg --purge --force-all modemmanager
(Reading database ... 124407 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing modemmanager (1.4.0-1) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/modemmanager not found.
dpkg: error processing package modemmanager (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/modemmanager not found.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 modemmanager
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution right afterwards:

```
% > /etc/init.d/modemmanager

% dpkg --purge --force-all modemmanager
(Reading database ... 124407 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing modemmanager (1.4.0-1) ...
Purging configuration files for modemmanager (1.4.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

I.e., to create an empty initscript, `/etc/init.d/modemmanager`.